# Override gitlab-ci pipeline variable before rules keyword

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I'm trying to make the gitlab-ci file for a deployment pipeline more dynamic and smarter. I have two systems that I'm deploying different product versions to. For each system it should not be possible to deploy from a feature branch, and if the DEPLOY_SYSTEM_X variable is set it should run automatically. Otherwise it should be a manual trigger. The pipeline looks something like this:

```
system1:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: never
    - if: $DEPLOY_SYSTEM_1 == "True"
      when: on_success
    - when: manual
  script:
    - <deploy_system.sh 1>

system2:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: never
    - if: $DEPLOY_SYSTEM_2 == "True"
      when: on_success
    - when: manual
  script:
    - <deploy_system.sh 2>
```

The variables DEPLOY_SYSTEM_X are set in the pipeline schedule.
To make it a bit sexier I would like to break out the rules-section, since they are so similar for the systems. The issue is that I need to do something smart with the DEPLOY_SYSTEM_X variable. I was thinking of introducing a DEPLOY_NIGHTLY variable that I can redefine in the different jobs like this

```
.common_rules:
 rules:
   - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
     when: never
   - if: $DEPLOY_NIGHTLY == "True"
     when: on_success
   - when: manual

system1:
  extends: .common_rules
  stage: deploy
  $DEPLOY_NIGHTLY = $DEPLOY_SYSTEM_1
  script:
    - <deploy_system.sh 1>

system2:
  extends: .common_rules
  stage: deploy
  $DEPLOY_NIGHTLY = $DEPLOY_SYSTEM_2
  script:
    - <deploy_system.sh 2>
```

But this obviously doesn't work since I cannot assign the $DEPLOY_NIGHTLY variable like that. Is this possible to accomplish at all? Is there anywhere in the job where I can redefine the variable? Or is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: `variables: DEPLOY_NIGHTLY: "${DEPLOY_SYSTEM_1}"` on the system jobs doesn't work? Are you using a self-hosted GitLab and if yes, are you using version 14.4 or higher?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.. I think the rules clause is being evaluated when the pipeline is built. And at that point it's too late for the variables to kick in on the job levels..
It's self hosted, but it's only on version 13.12.4